# C - dynamic function call

Tags: c, dynamic-function

I have a testing file with tests defined as

```
static int test1(){
    /*some tests here*/
    return 0;
}
static int test2(){
    /*some tests here*/
    return 0;
}
/*...etc*/`
```

and I was wondering if there's a way to call all of the tests in a loop, instead of writing the call for each one. (There are some functions I need to call before and after each test, and with >20 tests, this might get really annoying. I've also just been curious about doing things like this for a while.)

I was thinking something similar to:

```
int main(){
    int (*test)() = NULL;
    for(i = 1; i <= numtests; i++){
      /*stuff before test*/
      (*test)();
      /*stuff after test*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed with using the value of "i" to set the test pointer.

Comment: What platform are you on? Technically speaking, on a *NIX platform, you should be able to use `dlsym` and friends to dynamically invoke the function by name, though I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: I'm ssh'd into my school's linux servers. I have no idea what dlsym does, and I don't want to confuse myself right now, but I'll look it up later. A working (and fun-looking) solution was posted below, but thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self inclusion trick to get a list of function pointers:

```
#ifndef LIST_TESTS
#define TEST(name, ...) static int name() __VA_ARGS__

/* all includes go here */
#endif // ifndef LIST_TESTS

TEST(test1, {
  /* some tests here */
  return 0;
})

TEST(test2, {
  /* some tests here */
  return 0;
})

#undef TEST

#ifndef LIST_TESTS
int main(void) {
  int (*tests[])() = {
    #define LIST_TESTS
    #define TEST(name, ...) name,
    #include __FILE__
  };
  int num_tests = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]);
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < num_tests; ++i) {
    /* stuff before test */
    (tests[i])();
    /* stuff after test */
  }

  return 0;
}
#endif // ifndef LIST_TESTS
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a wonderful solution! Can you explain how the "__VA_ARGS__" part works? Does it just grab whatever is in the parameter slot for "..."?

Comment: @SaintlyWolf `__VA_ARGS__` gets replaced by whatever parameters were supplied to the macro at the `...` position. Without that construct, you would have trouble using commas in the test body. `LIST_TESTS` is defined in `main`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this. It's something I've wondered for a long while. Sadly, the compiler options my professor requires for this class prevent variadic macros. I'll be sure to remember this for after I'm done with this class, though!

Answer (score 1):

On linux

put the functions in a separate shared library (.so). Then use dlopen to open it and dlsym to get a function pointer by its name

On windows

put the functions in a separate dll (basically the same thing). Then use LoadLibrary to open it and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the function

A lot more typing that you wanted to do , but it will let you do what you want

Comment: While that may work, it's not actually useful for this purpose, as it doesn't simplify the process at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define an array of function pointers with all your functions and then loop in all elements of the array.

```
int (*array[])(void) = {test1, test2, test3};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd thought of that already, but was hoping for a method that doesn't involve typing the function names at all. Not saying I mind typing them, I just want to be able to do it, if the language allows.

Comment: @SaintlyWolf I cannot think of any better solution.

Comment: @SaintlyWolf You have to reference the actual function at some point.